# How to prioritize BDD's using specflow/xunit which runs using xunit runner

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow, xunit

Need help here:

We are using specflow with C# and my test cases run using xunit runner. Now i need to prioritize my BDD's/step definition files. We already have unit test cases for verification of pom's which uses [Fact]. Can i use the same thing in BDD's for prioritization of test cases or anything else helps me here

Comment: What do you mean by prioritizing?

Comment: Like giving priority to the test cases. Example ,if i have 10 bdd's , then instead of running it sequentially, can i give the order in which the bdd's/step definition can run.

Comment: I would advise against running your whole test case in a specific order in order to see the high priority test cases beeing run first. My suggested approach would be to tag the high-priority scenarios with a tag (eg @HighPrio) and only run these scenarios as some sort of smoketest. If these are OK, then you run your whole testsuite, or just the lower priority ones. For more information, take a look at Hooks in Specflow. This article explains it well: https://www.automatetheplanet.com/extend-test-execution-workflow-specflow-hooks/

Comment: In mstest we can specify tag like this @Priority(1)  @Priority(2)